# how to vectorize this string split function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I vectorize this strsplit function in Matlab so that it runs faster? Thank you

```
function parts = strsplit(splitstr, str)
  splitlen = length(splitstr);
  k = strfind(str, splitstr);
  parts = cell(length(k)+1, 1);
  s = 1;

  if isempty(k)
    parts{1} = str;
    return
  end

  for i=1:length(k)
    parts{i} = str(s : k(i)-1);
    s = k(i) + splitlen ;
  end

  parts{end} = str((k(end) + splitlen) : end);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace your function by a call to [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html).

```
str = 'testxyztest2xyztest3';
splitStr = 'xyz';
out = textscan(str,'%s','delimiter',splitStr,'multipleDelimsAsOne',1)
out{1}
ans = 
    'test'
    'test2'
    'test3'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html) (note also the [example on string splitting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html#brbuw4s-1) on that page):

```
out = regexp(str, regexptranslate('escape', splitStr), 'split');
```

The [regexptranslate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexptranslate.html) function escapes the split string so that it gets treated as a literal string and not a regular expression.